# CSS - Make image fit to div of a specific size

Tags: html, css, image

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
.d1 {
    background-color: green;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="d1">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3c/Cityoflondon2019june.jpg">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I use the above simple code to display an image inside a div of a specific size, but the image does not fit the div and overflows at bottom... How can I fix this? Ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the code:

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```